# How to subscribe a user to in-app alerts?

Tags: quickblox

I have no problem sending push notifications using Quickblox Messages module, but when I try to send an in-app alert, I get this error:

"No recipients. At least one user should be subscribed for In-app alert (through SDK or REST API)"

I was expecting that any user registered for push notifications would be able to receive in-app notifications but I'm guessing that's not the case. I went through QB documentation but can't find the code to subscribe a user to in-app alerts. What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Please specify whether you mean system pushes? As they got activated when application is in background or off.

Comment: I mean PULL messages (In-app alert). 
System pushes are working OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In-App notification channel was removed after 2014.04.4
http://quickblox.com/blog/2014/04/quickblox-released-some-server-updates/